# Thousand separator use space(" ") instead of "," [BATCH/CMD]

Tags: batch-file

I have this code in my batch/cmd file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "var1=9500"

set "var2="
set "sign="
if "%var1:~0,1%" equ "-" set "sign=-" & set "var1=%var1:~1%"
for /L %%i in (1,1,8) do if defined var1 (
   set "var2=,!var1:~-3!!var2!"
   set "var1=!var1:~0,-3!"
)
set "var2=%sign%%var2:~1%

echo %var2%
```

The output I get:

> 9,500

The output I want:

> 9 500

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself.
The one we don't want(line):

```
set "var2=,!var1:~-3!!var2!"
```

The one we DO want:

```
set "var2= !var1:~-3!!var2!"
```

As you can see, in the second one, I removed a comma.

Now I get this output:

> 9 500

Hope I helped :).